# Why would an application screenshot work with certain windows and be black for others

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I use this code to capture the window of an application.

```
Public Function CaptureWindow(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Image
   //get te hDC of the target window
   Dim hdcSrc As IntPtr = User32.GetWindowDC(handle)
   //get the size
   Dim windowRect As User32.RECT = New User32.RECT
   User32.GetWindowRect(handle, windowRect)
   Dim width As Integer = (windowRect.right - windowRect.left)
   Dim height As Integer = (windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top)
   //create a device context we can copy to
   Dim hdcDest As IntPtr = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc)
   //create a bitmap we can copy it to, using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
   Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height)
   //select the bitmap object
   Dim hOld As IntPtr = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap)
   //bitblt over
   GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY)
   //restore selection
   GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld)
   //clean up 
   GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest)
   User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc)
   //get a .NET image object for it
   Dim img As Image = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap)
   //free up the Bitmap object
   GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap)
   Return img
End Function
```

It works fine with most apps but I have an app for which it returns a black image. The image is of the right size but all black.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the app directly writes to the video memory? E.g. a Video player or a game could bypass GDI.

Comment: It is not a game. It is a phone application (X-Lite:  http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite.html). Probably not a .NET application, does it matter? If I take a screenshot of the whole desktop I do get it.

Comment: Please format code using the code formatting toolbutton (the one that looks like `{}`), selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K, or simply indenting by four spaces. Blockquote formatting should be used when, well, quoting a block of text. :-) Also, adding the appropriate language tag allows syntax highlighting of the code in most languages. Thanks.

Comment: Or the app uses DirectX, or the app is using transparency.